# JPA - Is any options simplify numbered columns set?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

I have some database table for inset matrix data.

the table has over than hundred columns named like [ColumnXXX]

| Column1 | Column2 | ... | Column100 |

Is any entity's annotation like this case for use it Or better options?

Previously, I used to reflection with foreach setColumnXXX. but it is not good performance to use.

```
for(int i = 0; i< tblColSize; i++){
  Object data = row.get(i);
  Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("setColumn"+i);
  method.invoke(data);
}
```

Comment: Naming columns like that is a bad practice. If you need to store dynamic data, look into JSONB data type.

Comment: It seems that you shouldn't really be using JPA in this case, it wasn't intended for such a thing (unless you want to declare 100 attributes/setters/getters). Why don't you just use JDBC and access your column values directly from the result set?